# how to pass authentication in http:put method at run time?

Tags: marklogic, http-put, usernametoken

I am running the below xqy code using a schedule task and in this xqy code, I am passing manually the value of authentication node with method="digest" username = admin password = admin in the put call,
Is there any way so that I can pass it at runtime using
1. Encrpyted token for username and password
2. getting the value username and password of the server at runtime , and passing it to the http-put function to access the rest service extension (/v1/resources/example) at 8000 port.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
    
    declare namespace hst = 'http://marklogic.com/xdmp/status/host';   
    declare namespace c = 'http://example.com/abc';  
    declare variable $Collection := 'collection';
    
    let $query :=    
         cts:and-query((   
            cts:collection-query($Collection),  
            cts:element-range-query(xs:QName('c:element'), '<=', fn:current-dateTime())  
        ))
          
    let $uris := cts:uris('',(), $query)   
    let $total-uri := count($uris)  
    return   
        if ($total-uri) then  
        let $PORT := '8000'   
        let $database := xdmp:database()  
        let $host-list := xdmp:hosts()    
        let $hosts :=     
                for $hosts-online in $host-list      
                where xdmp:host-status($hosts-online)/hst:hosts/hst:host[.//hst:online/fn:string() = 'true']    
                return $hosts-online                        
        let $cluster-size := fn:count($hosts)     
        return
            for $host at $index in $hosts       
            let $page-size := fn:ceiling($total-uri div $cluster-size)       
            let $start-index := ($index - 1) * $page-size + 1       
            let $end-index :=       
                if ($cluster-size eq $index)  then      
                    $total-uri       
                else         
                    ($index - 1) * $page-size +$page-size        
            let $urisforHost := string-join($uris[$start-index to $end-index],',')        
    
            let $url  := fn:concat('http://',xdmp:host-name($host),':',$PORT,'/v1/resources/example?rs:uris=',$urisforHost,'&amp;rs:db=',$database)
            return
                xdmp:spawn-function(function()
                    {xdmp:http-put($url,
                        <options xmlns="xdmp:http">
                           <authentication method="digest">
                             <username>admin</username>
                             <password>admin</password>
                           </authentication>
                     </options>
                    )
                    }
                )
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved using Secure Credentials by [creating a credential](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/security/secure-credentials#id_36331)

You then reference the credential id in your HTTP request, for example

```
xdmp:http-get("http://ml-node-1:8002/manage",
  <options xmlns="xdmp:http">
    <credential-id>{xdmp:credential-id("my-credential-name)}</credential-id>
  </options>)
```

Comment: For creating  a credential,we need username and password but we have not access of username and password as it will run in higher environment .Is there any way ,we can get the details of password and username for port 8000 on the fly,to pass it in http-put